# Use Angular 5 Component in Angular 1 tab View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular5

I have project in `angularJS` with Tab based system and every tab has its own view.

I want to develop new modules in `angular 2` in the same project , can you tell me how i can do it.

Project is developed in `angularJs` and also tab system working in this project with angularJs, so i want to create new component and will use this component in new Tab view.

Comment: Could you please clarify the problem more specific? If you want to move code from angular 1 to angular 2 it's not easy. It's better to re-write main logic to TypeScript and then put it to angular 2 components.

Comment: So what's your question? Have you tried something specific and it does not work?

Comment: no i don't want to move code from angular 1 to angular 2.

i have 4-5 modules in angular 1 and now want to create new module in the same project using angular 2 , so it means both angular 1 and angular 2 will  run together in same project.

my problem is that i am using tab system in project which i developed using angular 1 and each tab has seperate view

and now i want to call angular 2 component in the any tab view which i have developed using angular 1